# How can I get Hibernate to start version column at 1 for new objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Does anyone know if it is possible to get Hibernate to use 1 for the version (optimistic locking field) of a new object instead of zero? My application previously used Eclipselink which starts at 1 and the change is causing some problems.

I am using JPA but expect any solution to be Hibernate specific (a property in persistence.xml hopefully!).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question, and it's not explicitly mentioned in the docs ([even though it hints that it's possible](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#toolsetguide-s1-2)). I also wasn't able to find any tests for this scenario, so, it may be a good improvement for the Hibernate test suite ;-)

Anyway, Hibernate will work as you expect if you map your `@Version` property with a starting value:

```
@Version private int version = 1;
```